# How can I make this number format possible on Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, lambda, number-formatting

**The detail of my problem:**

I am using a table to track the size of some files in `Byte` by the built-in format `Number` with 1000 separator, example here `(Number) 1234 -> (Number with format) 1,234`. For my personal style, I want it to be display with a `000TB, 000GB, 000MB, 000KB, 000B` format, full example below.

| Original number | Number to be display with format (My goal) |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 111B |
| 111222 | 111KB, 222B |
| 111222333 | 111MB, 222KB, 333B |
| 111222333444 | 111GB, 222MB, 333KB, 444B |
| 111222333444555 | 111TB, 222GB, 333MB, 444KB, 555B |

**What did I try:**

(1) I tried the `Format Cells > Number > Custom` way so I can keep them in `Number` for the further calculation but is not perfect for my situation.

Format `[>999999999999]#"TB, "000"GB, "000"MB, "000"KB, "000"B";[>999999999]#"GB, "000"MB, "000"KB, "000"B";#"MB, "000"KB, "000"B"` is not perfect, good for TB and GB size, not good for MB KB and B size.

Format `[>999999999999]#"TB, "000"GB, "000"MB, "000"KB, "000"B";[>999999999]#"GB, "000"MB, "000"KB, "000"B";[>999999]#"MB, "000"KB, "000"B"` comes an error.

Yes I know it can only be `Positive Value; Negative Value; Zero Value` which can only supports for 2 cases and I need 5 cases.

(2) I tried the `Formulas > Name Manager > LAMBDA` function so they can be display as `Text` but not possible for further calculation again.

I use this function in my statistics table `=Sub.SizeFormat(SUMIFS(Table.List[Size(Byte)],Table.List[Month],[@Month],Table.List[Device],[@Device]))`.

| Name | Refers to |
| --- | --- |
| Sub.SizeFormat | =LAMBDA(Para_Size,CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(LEN(Para_Size)/3,0),Sub.SizeB(Para_Size),Sub.SizeKB(Para_Size),Sub.SizeMB(Para_Size),Sub.SizeGB(Para_Size),Sub.SizeTB(Para_Size))) |
| Sub.SizeB | =LAMBDA(Para_Size,SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(Para_Size,"#,##0."),".","ʙ")) |
| Sub.SizeKB | =LAMBDA(Para_Size,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(Para_Size,"#,##0."),",","ᴋ, ",1),".","ʙ")) |
| Sub.SizeMB | =LAMBDA(Para_Size,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(Para_Size,"#,##0."),",","ᴍ, ",1),",","ᴋ, ",2),".","ʙ")) |
| Sub.SizeGB | =LAMBDA(Para_Size,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(Para_Size,"#,##0."),",","ɢ, ",1),",","ᴍ, ",2),",","ᴋ, ",3),".","ʙ")) |
| Sub.SizeTB | =LAMBDA(Para_Size,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(Para_Size,"#,##0."),",","ᴛ, ",1),",","ɢ, ",2),",","ᴍ, ",3),",","ᴋ, ",4),".","ʙ")) |

**What am I expecting:**

Is there possible for me to insert units `TB GB MB KB B` according to the number and keeps them in `Number` for further calculation?

If not possible, better idea for my `LAMBDA` logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of applying the format directly to the cells, use conditional formatting, and apply different formats based on their values:

[image]

[image]